# Post Video To Facebook With ShareKit?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, sharekit

Is it possible to use some fork of ShareKit to post a video to facebook?  I don't want to mess with the whole Facebook graph API on my own, but would love ability to post videos.

Comment: I've never seen sharekit fork that can handle video uploading, but I don't think you will mess with the graph API. it's very simple https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/

Comment: I am coming across all sorts of problems with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/212) for video sharing in [ShareKit 2.0 repo](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) for some services, including Facebook. It is not merged yet, as there are some unresolved problems, most serious one is that if you share large video it exhausts device's memory.

But it might be a good start for you.

Comment: Do you know if there is any news on this pull request? It seems that it is still pending a merge into the main ShareKit, which means that if I use the pull request, I'll be missing all updates to the full ShareKit api for the last 7 months or so. I guess I could just do the merge locally, but if someone already has done this, that would obviously be preferable.

Comment: as you can see in pull request discussion, there some unresolved problems. That is why it is not merged yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the sharekit i suggest to use FBGraphAPI for this...

Here are the following steps, that you can post video on Facebook..

in .h file

```
#import "FbGraph.h"
#import "FbGraphFile.h"
#import "JSON.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    FbGraph                 *FB_Graph;
    FbGraphResponse         *FB_Graph_Response;
    FbGraphFile             *FB_Graph_File;
}

-(IBAction)btnShareVideoPress:(id)sender;

@end
```

in .m file call this method.....

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  NSString *ClientID = @"197556430726736";

  FB_Graph = [[FbGraph alloc]initWithFbClientID:ClientID];

  [FB_Graph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self      andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];

 }

-(IBAction)btnShareVideoPress:(id)sender
{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouTubeTest" ofType:@"m4v"]; 
NSURL *videoURL1=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSMutableDictionary *variables = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

FB_Graph_File = [[[FbGraphFile alloc] initwithURL:videoURL1]retain];

[variables setObject:FB_Graph_File forKey:@"file"];

[variables setObject:@"Test video upload 1" forKey:@"message"];
[variables setObject:@"video" forKey:@"MediaType"];
[FB_Graph doGraphPost:@"me/videos" withPostVars:variables];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graphresponse = [FB_Graph doGraphGet:@"me/videos/uploaded" withGetVars:variables];  

NSLog(@"postPictureButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graphresponse.htmlResponse);

 }
```

Comment: FbGraphFile has no interface for initWithURL. Please attach files you're using